# CURRENT_DATE in BigQuery result to yesterday's date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use current_date function in my BQ query to fecth today's data, but it was not working. After debugging I found out this function returns yesterday's data.

Unfortunately I am not able to add screenshot here.

Below is the query that I ran

Select current_date as the_date

result = 2020-08-20

it should be 2020-08-21

Any idea how to resolve this or how to fetch current datein big query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a time zone, it uses the default for your project.  I would guess your default is mis-configured.

Running these queries returns different results.

```
select current_date('US/Pacific') as the_date
select current_date('Australia/Melbourne') as the_date
```

Allowable time zone values are [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188), also on how to use the [current_date()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#current_date).